# Removing all extra white space within text file and pulling out strings-python

Tags: python

I have multiple text files in which I need to pull out two separate values that are the same line in each file. The values are integers but change in length. The following is what I have thus far.

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join('*_test.txt')):
hostname = file.split('_')[0]
with open(file) as data:

    for line in data:
        removed = line.strip()
        if removed:
            if line.startswith("test"):
                words= ''.join(removed[6:])
                print words
```

The output is currently the following

```
       3946207263      1904562885
        365872669       106578501
         205088500       25576835
```

My question is what would be the best way to remove all of the extra white space on the left and between the values. I am also getting stuck because the values change lengths so what would be the best way to pull out both values on each line if the lengths vary?

Comment: Try `'       3946207263      1904562885'.split()` (note that the comment format collapses whitespace, but `split` with no parameters concatenates all consecutive whitespace)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions to the rescue.

```
import re
RX_MANY_SPACES = re.compile('\s+')  # one or more spaces
# substitute many spaces with one
assert RX_MANY_SPACES.sub(' ', 'a    b       c') == 'a b c'
```

Alter to taste.